# If/elif/else неверно распознаёт выставленные критерии

Tags: python, if

Балуюсь с питоном (учусь).
В коде есть кусок с if/elif/else:

```
speed = input('Хотите посчитать быстро? (Да/Нет) ')

if speed == 'нет' or 'Нет':
    SlowCount()
elif speed == 'да' or 'Да':
    FastCount()
else:
    FastCount()
    print('Ваш ответ мне не ясен. Получите свои цифры и живите с ними в проклятом мире, который сами и создали.')
```

Ввожу в input "да". Ожидаю вызов FastCount(). Но программа выдаёт SlowCount().
Что бы я не ввёл в инпут, всегда будет включаться первый if.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: or работает не так как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Действительно, заработало. Спасибо!